# oracle forms FRM-40401 error raises when "execute_query" issued after "commit"

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

I have form that has button when clicked a smart trigger will be executed updating some columns but when I try to use after commit the following statement:

> *execute_query;*

i get

> ***FRM-40401 :*** no changes to save

how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXECUTE_QUERY` can't raise that message; it is `COMMIT` that does that.

If you need it (because you have to save changes you've made), then a simple option is to "mask" it, e.g.

```
:system.message_level := 25;
commit;
:system.message_level := 0;
```

In other words: set a message level to a high *level* so that the message you got isn't displayed (as its *message level* is lower than 25). After commit, restore the system message level to its default value (which is 0, meaning "display all messages").

Comment: but now it seems that execute_query is not executed since I am using it to refresh data block after the update but now it have no effect at all

Comment: Did you navigate to a data block which should be refreshed? How? Use `GO_BLOCK('that_block_name');` If the *focus* is somewhere else, nothing will happen. Also, make sure that changes you've made are really saved into the database. How? Establish a new connection (through SQL*Plus or SQL Developer or whichever tool you use) and SELECT data from the table.

Comment: that is right, I forgot go_block. thank you for your help